# Local maxima/minima theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

This nice theorem can be easily proved using Taylor's formula.
It gives us sufficient conditions for local extrema.

**Th:** Let $f(x)$ be defined in some interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ and let us assume it has up to
$n$-th derivative in some neighborhood $K = (a-\delta, a+\delta) \subset I$ of the point $a$.

Let also $f^{(n)}(x)$ be continuous at $a$. Let also:

$$f^{(k)}(a) = 0$$ for $k = 1,2,...,(n-1)$

and
$$f^{(n)}(a) \ne 0$$

Then:

$(1)$ if $n$ is even, then $f(x)$ has a local extremum at the point $a$
which is minimum if $f^{(n)}(a) \gt 0$ and is maximum if $f^{(n)}(a) \lt 0$

$(2)$ if $n$ is odd, then $f(x)$ has no local extremum at the point $a$

My question is the following... If $f$ satisfies condition $(2)$ of this theorem (and the other conditions), can we claim that

(A) *$f$ is even monotonous in some neighborhood $(a-\theta,a+\theta)$ of the point $a$*?

Or maybe... is it true that

*(B) we can construct a function $f$ (which satisfies the above mentioned conditions including (2)) such that for any neighborhood $(a-\theta,a+\theta)$  of the point $a$, $f$ has an extremum in that neighbourhood?*

In fact when I start thinking deeply about it, I am not even sure if (B) is the opposite of (A).
Or... are there other possible cases here too?

I mean (in the context of all said above), if $f$ has no local extrema in $(a-\theta,a+\theta)$, does it mean that it's monotonous in it? And vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is correct under the assumption that $f^{(n)} $ is continuous at $a$ 
By continuity of nth derivative at $a$, there exists a neighborhood of $a$ such that the nth derivative at $\alpha $ and at $a$ have the same sign. Let $f^{(n)} (a) \gt 0$, where $n=2k+1$ is odd number. 
By Taylor's theorem, there exists $\alpha \in (a, x) $ such that :
$f(x) = f(a) +\sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1}\frac{f^{(i)}(a)} {i!}(x-a) ^i+ \frac{f^{(n)} (\alpha)}{(n)!} (\alpha) (x-a) ^{n} =f(a) +\frac{f^{(2k+1)} (\alpha)}{(2k+1)!}  (x-a) ^{2k+1}\implies f'(x) =\frac{f^{(2k+1)}(\alpha) }{(2k+1)(2k)!}  (2k+1) (x-a) ^{2k}=\frac{f^{(2k+1)}(\alpha) }{(2k)!}  (x-a) ^{2k}\gt 0 \tag{1} $ 
**Edit:**
*Mr. Peter Petrov has pointed out in comments that the problem with $(1)$ is that $\alpha$ depends upon $x$ so differentiating the Taylor series above is going to be complicated*. 
Therefore, Taylor series for $f'(x) $ can be written as above whence it will be clear that $f'(x) $ is positive in some neighborhood of $a$, which proves the monotonicity of $f$.

The same process as above can be employed for the case when $f^{(n)} (a)  \lt 0$.

Comment: I see your idea but I am not sure I follow the calculations. Are you sure of them? How did you make the implication there? And why did the $(2k+1)$ term disappear?

Comment: Thanks for the idea (despite the imprecise calculation). I think you should have written Taylor's formula for $f'$ rather than $f$. In fact your way works too, but you saved a few details. Never mind. I think (A) is indeed correct. I am pretty sure now.

Comment: @peter.petrov: I might have missed a few calculation details. But I'm glad that you found this helpful and got the idea and that was the intention of this answer actually. About $(2k+1)$ th term, please note that nothing disappeared! To be more precise, $f(x) = f(a) +\frac{f^{(n)} (\alpha)}{n!}  (x-a) ^n=f(a) +\frac{f^{(2k+1)} (\alpha)}{(2k+1)!} (\alpha) (x-a) ^{2k+1}\implies f'(x) =\frac{f^{(2k+1)}(\alpha) }{(2k+1)(2k)!}  (2k+1) (x-a) ^{2k}==\frac{f^{(2k+1)}(\alpha) }{(2k)!}  (x-a) ^{2k}\gt 0$

Comment: @peter.petrov: Calculations are correct. I think the improper/imprecise typesetting is what might have confused you. Updated the same accordingly. And you really don't have to write Taylor series for $f'(x) $ as writing the same for $f(x) $ followed by differentiating both sides works too. In fact, I wrote series for $f(x) $ as this is how sufficient condition for local maxima /minima  is derived. Although, you may start by writing Taylor series for $f'(x) $ also.

Comment: Oh OK, I didn't realize you differentiated both sides. OK... Thanks. So my answer here is also valid, I assume.

Comment: @peter.petrov: I have gone through your answer. It is correct except that you have missed one crucial detail there. Signs of $g^{(n-1)}(\mu)$ and that of $g^{(n-1)}(a)$ are the same in some neighbourhood. This requires some explanation, which is that: since $g^{(n-1)}$ is continuous at $a$, there exists a neighborhood of $a$ in which $g^{(n-1)}$ has same sign as that of $g^{(n-1)}(a)$. Let's call this neighborhood $I$. Now apply Taylor's theorem in that interval $I$. This will complete the proof.

Comment: Yeah... no... I didn't miss it, I maybe just didn't phrase it well. Thanks. So anyway (A) is actually correct. It was my intuition that (A) must be correct, and now we have it formally proven. Thanks.

Comment: In fact, I don't think you can differentiate both sides just like that. Why? Because this $\alpha$ is not a fixed number (it is not independent of $x$). It's a function of $x$. So if you differentiate both sides it will get messy, you will need to get involved with the derivative of $\alpha$ w.r.t. $x$. So maybe my approach with just applying Taylor's formula to $g(x) = f'(x)$ is more convincing, more sound. Right?

Comment: @peter.petrov: I think you are right. $\alpha$ is indeed dependent on $x$. So differentiation is going to be complicated. Writing Taylor series directly for $f'$ can get the job done easily. You are right. Thanks. I have updated the answer & not deleted it. Let it be here so that "Donts" is also visible with $Do's".

Comment: Sure... Thank you. It's good to have someone to brainstorm with. I realized that "minor" problem with $\alpha$ today while thinking this whole thing over. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this proof of (A) correct?

Let $g(x) = f'(x)$

Then we use Taylor's formula for $g$ i.e. for $f'$ in the given neighborhood $K = (a-\delta, a+\delta)$

$$g(x) = (\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \frac{g^{(k)}(a)}{k!} (x-a)^{k}) + \frac{g^{(n-1)}(\mu)}{(n-1)!} (x-a)^{n-1}$$

where $\mu$ lies between $x$ and $a$.

And then we use the facts that

i) all terms in the $\Sigma$ sum are zeros and
ii) the function $g^{(n-1)} = f^{(n)}$ is continuous at $a$

The latter means there is a neighborhood $T$ of $a$ in which $g^{(n-1)} = f^{(n)}$ is either positive or negative (I mean in the whole neighborhood $T$).

And then from

$$g(x) =  \frac{g^{(n-1)}(\mu)}{(n-1)!} (x-a)^{n-1}$$

$($which is valid for all $x \in V = K \cap T$$)$

and taking into account that $(n-1)$ is even, we conclude that the sign of $$g(x) = f'(x)$$ doesn't change in that neighborhood $V$.

And that means $f$ is either increasing or decreasing in the neighborhood $V$ of $a$.